# 'ngModel' cannot be binded to 'ion-input'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel, angular-standalone-components

I am using ionic 7 with angular to build social app and I want to use two way binding to get the data from the input field but ngModel is not recognise
Here is the html content:

```
<div class="post-input">
<ion-item>
  <ion-input
    placeholder="Write your today's post ..."
    [(ngModel)]="postText"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
  ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-button class="post-btn" color="medium" (click)="post()">
  <ion-icon name="pencil-outline"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

and the ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule],
})
export class HomePage {

  postText!: string
  constructor() {}

  post() {

  }
}
```

Now I am getting the error Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input' and the old solutions is not working.

Comment: Do you import `FormsModule`?

Comment: I imported FormsModule in app.component.ts

Comment: @Xyz.WebDeveloper its a standalone component so you need to import the FormsModule in the component to access it.

Answer (score 3):

The inputs for template-driven forms, such as `ngModel` and `ngModelOptions`, are only available when importing `FormsModule` in your standalone feature component (or feature module):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule, FormsModule],
})
```

It's not enough to import `FormsModule` in your standalone root component (or root module).

For more information, see the [Angular guide on building a template-driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have imported the FormsModule in your app.module.ts file.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ]
})
```

If you are still having an issues, make sure you have imported "Ionicmodule" and "Commonmodule" in your app.module.ts file.

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule       
   ],  
})
```

Comment: There is no app.module.ts in ionic 7

Comment: if you are using Angular with IONIC then app.Module.ts file must be there. Path is "src/app" folder.

Comment: It isn't available in ionic 7. I tried the above solution where I import it in my standalone component and it worked

Comment: glad to hear that your problem has been solved

Comment: This answer is not correct. The `FormsModule` needs to be imported in the *feature* module and not in the *root* module.

Comment: @JSONDerulo refer article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-formsmodule-directive/

Comment: The example in this article only works because for the sake of simplification, the code lives in `app.component.html`. However in real world, this is very rarely the case. Also in the question the code is clearly not in the root (app) component.